# Windows 7 using French AZERTY keyboard special characters problem

Tags: keyboard, windows, internationalization

After a long struggle I got successfully installed Windows 7(OS in English but French Keyboard) in Lion OS X Using Boot-Camp. Followed this I have installed all the windows necessary driver software's but I have some problem with the special characters.

I couldn't find out the symbols like @ ! § { } + =.

How can I change the layout of this keyboard???

Comment: Could you clarify -- is this with bootcamp or Fusion or Parallels?  Also are you saying that your Win 7 keyboard layout is set to French or that you have an Azerty hardware keyboard attached to your Mac or both?

Comment: @Tom Gewecke : it's with boot-camp. I have installed the boot camp assistant software for windows.

Comment: I ask again:  Also are you saying that your Win 7 keyboard layout is set to French or that you have an Azerty hardware keyboard attached to your Mac or both?

Comment: @Tom Gewecke: Yes, in Win 7 even after the keyboard layout is set to French & the keyboard driver software is installed, still the layout hasn't changed. For example to have ! this character i have to press =+ key on windows 7.

Comment: What kind of hardware keyboard are you using?

Comment: @Tom Gewecke: It's a default built-in mac keyboard.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I didn't realize there are 2 versions of French keyboard i.e 1.French 2.French Apple in the keyboard settings.

Chose French Apple keyboard from settings, resolved my problem.